# Find $f_{1}, f_{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z_{6}}[x]$ such that deg$(f_{1})$ = deg$(f_{2}) = 2$ and deg$(f_{1}+f_{2})=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

1. Find $f_{1}, f_{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z_{6}}[x]$ such that deg$(f_{1})$ = deg$(f_{2}) = 2$ and deg$(f_{1}+f_{2})=1$
2. Find $g_{1}, g_{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z_{6}}[x]$ such that deg$(g_{1})$ = deg$(g_{2}) = 1$ and deg$(g_{1}.g_{2})=1$

Comment: Your solution to 1. is correct. For 2., look for polynomials of the type $g_1(x):=ax+b$, $g_2(x)=cx+d$, $a\neq\bar0$, $c\neq\bar0$. What must the coefficients satisfy in order for $\mathrm{deg}(g_1\cdot g_2)=1$?

Comment: Thanks. I also did the second one.

Comment: Your solution to 2. is also correct.

Comment: Yay. Thanks again :)

Comment: Perhaps you could post your solution as an answer and accept it. Just include your thought process so that it may be of help to visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have came up with this solution.

(1)  Let $f_{1}(x) = \bar{3}x^2+\bar{2}x+\bar{1}$ and $f_{2}(x) = \bar{3}x^2+x+\bar{2}$, which are of degree $2$.

Then, $(f_{1}+f_{2}) = \bar{6}x^2 + \bar{3}x + \bar{3} = \bar{0}x^2 + \bar{3}x + 3$ is of degree $1$.

(2) Let $g_{1}(x) = 3+2x$ and $g_{2}(x) = 2+3x$, which are of degree $1$.

Then, $(g_{1}.g_{2}) = \bar{6} + \bar{13}x = \bar{0} + x$ is of degree $1$.